# Most Frequent Number in a Number

Tags: python

Goal is to work out the most common digit in a long number. For example 213523432455555555 would return 5.

```
print('Question 4')



def most_frequent(number):
    analysisnumber=map(int,str(number))
    returnvalue=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
highest = 0
total2=0
for i in range(0,len(str(number))):
    returnvalue[analysisnumber[i]] = list(map(i,analysisnumber))
for i in range(0,20):
    if i < 10:
        if returnvalue[i] > highest:
            highest = returnvalue[i]
    if i > 10:
        if returnvalue[i-10] == highest:
            total2+=highest
print("The most frequent number",end="")
if total2 > highest:
    print("s are: ")
    for i in range(0,10):
        if returnvalue[i] == highest:
            print(i)
else:
    print(" is ", end="")
    for i in range(0,10):
        if returnvalue[i] == highest:
            print(i)
            break
number=int(input("Enter the number intended for analysis:"))
most_frequent(number)
```

I get the

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

error. Would love some help!

Comment: Could you please add extra information about the error. At which line it occurs?

Comment: There will be some line number information with error message. Check what is exactly happening there.

Comment: Presumably, you mean in decimal? A number is a number. How you choose to represent it is not part of the number. 2^(2^2) == 10000 in binary, 16 in decimal, 20 in octal, 10 in hexadecimal, etc.

Comment: File "/Users/fizzhazlt/Documents/TEST3.py", line 106, in <module>
    most_frequent(number)
  File "/Users/fizzhazlt/Documents/TEST3.py", line 85, in most_frequent
    returnvalue[analysisnumber[i]] = list(map(i,analysisnumber))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do, use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> i = 24325872039847324509823475
>>> c = Counter(str(i))
>>> c
Counter({'2': 5, '3': 4, '4': 4, '5': 3, '7': 3, '8': 3, '0': 2, '9': 2})
>>> max(c.items(), key= lambda (x,y): y)
('2', 5)
```

Or just use(thanks to @tobias_k):

```
>>> c.most_common(1)
[('2', 5)]
```

Comment: Does this mean I have to download Counter, or is it in pyton (3.4.3) by default?

Comment: @Fizzhaz, Its python standard

Comment: for some reason when I import it it claims print('sdafas') is invalid syntax?

Comment: Instead of `max`, just use `c.most_common(1)`.

Comment: @Fizzhaz, that is weird.... look over your code searching for that print

Comment: When I used @tobias_k's suggestion it worked properly, thanks guys!

Comment: I think tuple-unpacking in lambda-parameters, as in `lambda (x,y):` only works in some python version. If you use `key= lambda t: t[1]` it should work.

Answer (score 5):

you are using the map function wrong.

```
returnvalue[analysisnumber[i]] = list(map(i,analysisnumber))
```

the first value to map (from the documentation) is function): `map(function, iterable, ...)`

you supplied it with an int (i).